# Php reversal of this function?

Tags: php

What is the revesal of this function? Array to object in recursive way ?

```
function obj2array($obj) {
  $out = array();
  foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
    switch(true) {
        case is_object($val):
         $out[$key] = obj2array($val);
         break;
      case is_array($val):
         $out[$key] = obj2array($val);
         break;
      default:
        $out[$key] = $val;
    }
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: Did you already try to typecast from object to array like `var_dump((array) $someobject)` ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP array conevrt into an object by casting it to an object:

```
$array = array(
    // ...
);
$object = (object) $array;
```

Manually convert the array into an object:

```
$object = object;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $object->{$key} = $value;
}
```

Comment: if `$key` is numeric it's going to create object property that can't be accessed, did you already try it yourself ?

Comment: yes that was the issue, it creates likes $public->$0